# colorful background of the chapters in ToC without ''tocloft'' package

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I would like to create a table of contents where the chapters appear with a colorful background just like attached Image,  and i hope to do this without `tocloft` ( without packages or with `titletoc` )

[image]

an attempt by Beginner

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{section}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\titlecontents*{chapter}
  [0pt]
  {\addvspace{1mm}}
  {\colorbox{MidnightBlue}{\textcolor{white}%       
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel}}}
  {}
  {\colorbox{MidnightBlue}{\textcolor{white}%       
  {\hspace{7.5cm}\contentspage}}}

\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \stdl@chapter{\colorbox{MidnightBlue}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}{\textcolor{MidnightBlue}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please explain why you wish to accomplish your objective *without* using a specialized LaTeX package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way apart from deep hacks, is to put a tight`tcolorbox` around the `\l@chapter` command, which is redefined and called internally with the standard values. However, this introduces some vertical spacing above and below the chapter toc entries.

The colours are hardcoded at the moment.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\let\standardlistchapter\l@chapter%

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback={MidnightBlue},
  coltext={white},
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,%
  left=0pt,top=-10pt,
  right=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  auto outer arc]
\standardlistchapter{\textcolor{white}{#1}}{\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%




\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{section}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%

\chapter{Chapter one}

\section{First}

\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Chapter two}

\section{First}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]